# Should I split data or allow fragmentation

Tags: network-programming

I am preparing to write a program that will be sending/receiving UDP datagrams.

Here is my question:
Should I manage the data so that what I am sending will fit in a single datagram? Basically splitting the data within the application and then sending multiple datagrams. Or, should I allow the network to handle the fragmentation and reassembly?

I am assuming standard MTU size of 1500 bytes. In theory, the maximum UDP payload on top of IPv4 is 65507 bytes.

Performance/overhead info, best practices, and other information is appreciated.

Comment: The real question is why do you care, is this performance dependant, or do you require consistency and assured delivery?

Comment: It is UDP, so delivery is never guaranteed. I guess I am asking from a performance standpoint, and is probably more theoretical. If I wanted to serve as many clients as possible, while hoping for (but not depending on) no loss of data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP stack layers (and OSI layers) are designed so that works in one layer are transparent to upper layers. So, initially, you don't have to worry about how you send the data. You should know only aspects related to UDP: connectionless, unreliable ... and shouldn't care about IP layer.

I cannot see any advantage in considering the MTU at a higher layer unless you have your own custom stack.

Comment: That's kinda what I was trying to get at with this question. Does it matter if I just send as much data as I can in the UDP packet and let the network fragment it, or should I take the time (Processing and coding) to make all the data fit into a packet with standard MTU size.

Comment: @n01d3a, don't worry about the MTU, send everything you have to send. There shouldn't be any problem. Just try it! With a few lines of code, client and server, you can test it in max 4 hours.